# angular select with 2 item selected

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with a few listbox loaded from a service: most of them are working correctlty, but 3 have a problem: the list is populated correctly, the ng-model variable is set correctly, but the the item is not selected.
Checking with batarang found this:

```
<select class="required form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" data-ng-options="tipoVia.id as tipoVia.descrizione for tipoVia in vm.tipiViaEdit" data-ng-model="vm.recordSelect.tipoVia" data-ng-change="vm.filtroTipoViaEdit()">
<option value="0" selected="selected" label="(--)">(--)</option>
...
<option value="62" label="SVINCOLO">SVINCOLO</option>
<option value="63" selected="selected" label="TRAVERSA">TRAVERSA</option>
<option value="64" label="TRAVERSA DI">TRAVERSA DI</option></select>
...
```

for same strange reason looks like that two items are flagged with selected: do you know when this may be happens? I have looked a few times but I don't understand how I can do this.

**Update**:
After the call to the server to receive the data, I set the options and compare with the model to see if is found in the array, and the value is found

```
        this.tipiViaEdit = data.tipiVia;

        this.tipiViaEdit.forEach(myString => {
            if (myString.id === this.recordSelect.tipoVia) {
                alert("value found");
            }
        });
```

Luca

Comment: is your model an array?

Comment: I tried with both an array of string and an array of objects

Comment: if your model is an array and the array has 2 elements then those elements will be marked as selected in your select . of you want only one element to be selected then you need to make your model a primitive type not an array

Comment: as you can see from the value in the sample, the array contains more da 70 elements

Comment: thats the list of available values. i am talking about your model

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon, that is not correct. It will only select multiple elements if it is `<select multiple>`. Otherwise, it will override the array with the selected object

Comment: select multiple allows the user to select more than one, there is no written rule about linking an array to a single select if he is altering the model using the on-change event

Comment: If the model is an array, only the default blank option will be selected (unless it's select multiple) http://plnkr.co/edit/MROCXXeB3xKOfGTu2esf?p=preview

Comment: the proeprty in the ng-model is a string

Comment: There is something else going on here that is not evident from the code you posted.

Comment: I already supposed this, in fact I was trying to understand in which condition angular set more than 1 item as selected. the strange thing is that the first item of the list is always selected, is not dependent on the value of the first item

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the problem and I share to solution hoping may be useful for others: in the page I'm using a grid to show a list of objects, and selecting one of the rows the object is used in the editing form.
Looks like that the problem was that the same object is bound both to the grid and to the components in the form, giving different result with differents properties: some of the fields in the form was bound correctly, others not.
I rehydrate the object from the server, downloading a new one along with the list components and this way the form works.